# s7-Out, send a Boolean value to a PLC uing Node-RED

Tags: node-red, plc

I'm trying to send the value true or false to my variable test in the PLC, using the node S7, but it doesn't work when I put the adress : DB3,X42.0 or even DB3,BOOL42.0.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are the any errors?

Comment: no erros but, just I don't receive the comand from node-RED in the PLC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Node S7, but the normal Siemens naming would be:

```
DB3.DBX42.0
```

Comment: instead of the first dot (.) is comma (,) it is DB3,DBX42.0 not DB3.DBX42.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I have to change the string length to 30, so instead of DB3,S10.32 I have to put DB3.S10.30, because the lenght of the string is 30, and you have to put the lenght of the string after the offset number. the value 32 was like an excess of memory that is why I didn't receive anything in the next value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use db1,x14.1 for example to address Boolean tags inside a data block
in my example it was bit 14.1 from data block db1.

BR.

Ghassan